# PHP regular expression to match two needles

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to extract 2 elements from a string into an array. The string is a weather feed:

```
Thursday at 08:00 BST: white cloud. 10°C (50°F)
```

I want the "**white cloud**" and "**10°C**" parts. So I need to match between "**BST:**" and "**.**" as well as between " " and "**°C**".

I'm struggling with the regular expression(s) I need and would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
preg_match('/: (.*?)\. (-?\d+)/', $str, $matches);
```

Things to watch out for:

- Don't match on BST or it'll break in winter when we move to GMT
- Watch out for negative temperatures

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
^\w+ at \d{2}:\d{2} BST: ([^.]+)\. (-?\d+°C)
```

If there is not a single space between the words, replace them with `\s+`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
/BST: (.*) ([0-9]+°C)/
```

Should work although you may have a problem matching the ° if do try:

```
/BST: (.*) ([0-9]+.C)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*capture groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Anything within round parantheses will be captured (by default) and you can fetch what they matched later:

```
:\s+([^.]*)\s+([\d]*)
```

If that is your regular expression you can use it with [`preg_match`](http://de3.php.net/preg_match):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/:\s+([^.]*)\s+([\d]*)/', $string, $matches);
```

`$matches` will then contain the contents of the capture groups.